# After Effects Prevent Widows in Text

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

So I'm pulling in text from a csv and I am trying to find a way to prevent widows (where there is a single word on a line).

in JS we'd do this `text = text.replace(/\s(?=[^\s]*$)/g, '&nbsp;');`

But I can't seem to find a similar method in After Effects with expressions, to insert a nonbreaking space between the last word and the second last word in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much information about this. I have found a discussion where someone said there could be a bug with regex lookahead, maybe it's not even implemented ([source](https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects/regexp-bug/td-p/8904775)).

Instead, you could capture the last word and add it along with the space (captured elements start with index 1, so $1 is the first and in this case only group):

```
text = text.replace(/\s([^\s]*$)/g, " $1");
```

Comment: Only issue is that I can't seems to place a non-breaking space that AF respects and doesn't just treat as a regular space.

Comment: used \u2007 to create the space. Only issue was that it started breaking words onto the next line. lol Can never win.